# Bootstrap Center Column Drop Down. Right and Left Columns Come Together

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

Is it possible to have 3 columns (3,6,3) on a wide screen but when brought to mobile or iPad size, the center column drops down so you effectively have the 2 '3' columns come together as '6','6' and under them stacks the full width '12' column?

Currently I have tried the html below, but this stacks them all three on top of each other at the mobile level, rather than dropping the center down to it's own new row.

```
 <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">TESTING LEFT</div>
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">TESTING MID</div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">TESTING RIGHT</div>

     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way to do this is to create two "Mid" divs, show one when the screen is large, but hide that one when the screen is small.  Hide it by adding `hidden-md` and `hidden-lg`.  Also add `hidden-sm` and `hidden-xs` to the first one.

I created a demo with styling so you can see the different divs more easily.

#### [Bootply Demo](http://www.bootply.com/vcsMh3krRa)

```
<div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">TESTING LEFT</div>
         <div class="hidden-sm hidden-xs col-xs-12 col-md-6">TESTING MID</div>
         <div class="col-xs-6 col-md-3">TESTING RIGHT</div>
     </div>
     <div class="row hidden-md hidden-lg">
         <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6">TESTING MID</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

[image]

In your situation, you can do that with push and pull classes:

```
   <div class="container">
     <div class="row">
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3">LEFT md first in content</div>
         <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-3 col-md-push-6">Right md Second in content </div>
         <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-pull-3 col-md-6">Central MD last in content</div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

DEMO: http://jsbin.com/muvov/1/